# Connecting two bots on Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

How to connect to another deployed bot (may be by using it's botId and secret) from my bot?
(Scenario: when my bot does not understand user's query, it has to then forward the query to another bot to check if it knows the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using Direct Line.

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a
>   single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own
>   client applications, web chat controls, mobile apps, or
>   service-to-service applications that will talk to their bot.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLineWebSockets) you will find some C# samples on how to use the API.