# Connecting two bots on Microsoft Bot Framework on same server

Tags: c#, botframework

I have similar problem [with connect two bots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853535/connecting-two-bots-on-microsoft-bot-framework)

The suggested solution with Direct Line seems overkill since my second bot running on the same server. Can I simply use HttpClient with PostAsync? What is the best approach for rerouting activity received in Post controller?

```
public async Task Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
```

I believe I need to copy all headers used for authentication?

Comment: DirectLine is probably your best bet here, why do you think it's overkill?

Comment: since it is on same server - why do I need go to outside through the internet instead of direct post to local bot.